# Gradually coloring edges in terms of their vertices colors

Tags: graphs-and-networks, color

In order to color `Edges` in a `Graph` after applying a function such as `VertexDegree` I did the following code (on *Mathematica 8.0.4*):

```
g = GridGraph[{4, 4},VertexLabels->"Name",ImagePadding->10,DirectedEdges->True];
(* highlight is taken from the documentation of VertexDegree *)
highlight = Table[
  Style[VertexList[g][[i]],
    ColorData["TemperatureMap"][VertexDegree[g][[i]]/Max[VertexDegree[g]]]],
  {i, VertexCount[g]}];
edgeList = EdgeList@g;
Flatten@Table[{edgeList[[i]] -> (
  Function[Evaluate@
    Line[#, VertexColors -> {highlight[[edgeList[[i, 1]], 2]], 
       highlight[[edgeList[[i, 2]], 2]]}]])},
  {i,Length@edgeList}];

HighlightGraph[SetProperty[g, EdgeShapeFunction -> %], highlight]
```

giving me:

[image: Graph with colored edges]

which is basically what I was waiting for in terms of what it should look like.

Although since I'm using `Line[#, VertexColors -> {Color1, Color2}]` the fact that the `Edges` are either `Directed` or `Undirected` is not preserved in the `Graph`.

**Thus my question is:**

Is there a way to preserve the `DirectedEdge`/`UndirectedEdge` property and to gradually color the `Edges` in terms of its two vertices?

Comment: Quick fix would be to modify your `EdgeRenderingFunction` with: `Function[Evaluate@{Arrow[#], Line[#,___]}]`. Do you need something like that but with `DirectedEdge/UndirectedEdge`?

Comment: Something which takes into account the property of the edge would be great :)

Comment: And I was also hoping that someone could have a solution using `EdgeStyle`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since VertexColors is only way to set colors of line gradually, I don't think there's way to control with EdgeStyle.  One thing you can do is by define two edge shape functions which defer by edges:

```
eStyle[colors_][pts_, UndirectedEdge[x_, y_]] := 
 (Line[pts, VertexColors -> {colors[[x]], colors[[y]]}]) 
eStyle[colors_][pts_, DirectedEdge[x_, y_]] :=
  {colors[[y]], Arrow[Line[pts, VertexColors -> {colors[[x]], colors[[y]]}]]}
```

Directed graph:

```
g = GridGraph[{4, 4}, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10,  DirectedEdges -> True];

colors = ColorData["TemperatureMap"] /@ (VertexDegree[g]/Max[VertexDegree[g]]);
HighlightGraph[SetProperty[g, EdgeShapeFunction -> eStyle[colors]],
     Thread[Style[VertexList[g], colors]]]
```

[image]

Undirected graph:

```
g = GridGraph[{4, 4}, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10];

colors = ColorData["TemperatureMap"] /@ (VertexDegree[g]/Max[VertexDegree[g]]);
HighlightGraph[SetProperty[g, EdgeShapeFunction -> eStyle[colors]], 
  Thread[Style[VertexList[g], colors]]]
```

[image]